# RequireJs magento2 loading custom js plugin results in DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, jquery, requirejs

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector.

this is my code in main.js file.

```
require([ 'rellax'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("entered the function rellax");
    var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax', {
        callback: function (position) {
            console.log(position);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "js/main"
    ],
    map: {
    '*': {
        slick: 'js/slick.min',
        rellax: 'js/rellax.min'
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: if i remove the $(document).ready(function () then it throws Uncaught ReferenceError: Rellax is not defined

Comment: 1. Add `domReady!` as a dependency rather than using the jQuery .ready method. 2. What happens if you remove the rellax code and dependency? That can narrow it down to either rellax itself or whether it's how you've added the JS.

Comment: Hi ben, i remove .ready and added ['jquery', 'rellax', 'domReady!'], still its the same, gettng rellax undefined

Comment: please share your full path of js js/rellax.min

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(['jquery', 'rellax', 'domReady!'], function ($, rellax, domReady) {
    console.log("entered the function rellax");

    var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax', {
        callback: function (position) {
            console.log(position);
        }
    });
});
```

I have added jQuery and domReady! as a dependency and removed the jQuery `.ready()` method.

If you are getting errors about rellax being undefined then it sounds like you're either using Rellax wrong or your paths are incorrect. If you still get the error, is the console log working?

Comment: Hi I am still getting the error as Rellax is not defined, the file is getting called for sure but looks like its not initialised

Comment: It sounds like it's either a problem with rellax or how you're using it, unless I'm missing something if this file and rellax are loading fine it doesn't sound like a Magento issue.

Comment: I tried this with simple html and css. It seemed to work fine but here with requirejs it seems to be a problem. Any idea how to debug it?

Comment: It may even be an issue with Rellax:  https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax/issues/61 and https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax/issues/22

Comment: one of the issues being that it was not working as the rellax was called before defining, but in our case using requireJS that shouldnt happen, so what do i do here to resolve this, been stuck with this for 3 days already

Comment: I've never used Realax so I have no idea sorry, I've never experienced this issue with the jQuery libraries I've used. What if you try initialising it using Javascript rather than jQuery?

Comment: Oh you know the issue was because there was 'define' used inside the JS plugin. i removed those and it seems to work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66642/discussion-between-sylvester-and-ben-crook).